# Multilevel JSON data from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am trying to access latitude & longitude values from here->

```
https://graph.facebook.com/79537378027/albums
```

here is what I am trying

```
$File= file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/79537378027/albums');
$p=json_decode($File);
foreach ($p->data as $loc)
{
echo $loc->place[0].latitude;}
```

But I am not getting values. If I try with simple `$loc->latitude` it won't give me anything as latitude is a sub-child of place.

Comment: The dot is the string concatenation operator _only_ in PHP. Please set the error_reporting of your test system to a sensible value.

Comment: @CBroe didn't get what you said

Comment: `$loc->place[0].latitude` does not make any sense syntax-wise.

Comment: @CBroe I know then how can I access latitude ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$File= file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/79537378027/albums');
$p=json_decode($File);
foreach ($p->data as $loc)
{
    if($loc->place) {
        echo $loc->place->location->latitude;
    }
}

?>
```